# How to add a colum (time of operation) to many-to-many relations table?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have one table or domain entity ChargaOperation, which is mapped to table **[ChargeOperation]**
and has a many-to-many relations with itself. It's like an offset of client's debts or a tree of distributions (parent and 1 level of children).

```
ChargeOperation
{
  int Id,
  decimal Amount,
  IList<ChargeOperation>  DistributedDebts // a tree of distributions using many to many mapping
}
```

relations a realized with a help of **[Distribtions]** table which has mapping in code and mapped like this:

```
 public ChargeOperationMap()
    {
        Table("ChargeOperations");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Amount).Not.Nullable().Column("Amount");


        HasManyToMany(x => x.DistributedDebts).Table("Distributions]")
                     .ParentKeyColumn("SourceId")
                     .ChildKeyColumn("SubjectId")
                     .Cascade.All();
    }
```

table **[Distribtutions]** has fields:

- SourceId
- SubjectId.

  SourceId is an id of parent ChargeOperation.Id & subjectId is a child (one of IList  DistributedDebts).
  It's was ok, until I have to add a time for each operation of distribution and change field of table **[Distribtutions]** like this:

  - SourceId
  - SubjectId
  - TimeOfOperation

And now only one oportunity to do it is to create an mapping of Distribtutions, break the many-to-many relations and create two one-to-many relations. 
How can I avoid it and just write timeOfOperation to **[Distribtutions]**. (I read it with a view, so it's not a poblem for reading)

Comment: You definitely SHOULD break the many-to-many relationship because now it's not what it really is. Your Distribution is now full-fledged entity itself (even conceptually), so just make it clearer for everbody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you could always add a default value of `GetDate()` to the `timeOfOperation` column.

Then whenever the many-to-many table is inserted into the `timeOfOperation` column will receive the current datetime. Since you say that this column is read out from a view then you don't need to map it at all.

Comment: no. I don't need a systemTime of smth. I need to save my time of operation